# Why does my DVD+R show more usage than I burned?

Tags: windows-7, dvd, burning

I burned 24 MB (4 files) to DVD+R but on disk properties in Windows it shows up 28 MB of used space. Why is so large difference?
There are no hidden files. I used Windows 7 burning system in Explorer `(Mastered Format)` with Verbatim disk.

Comment: Have you check the bit size and/or hash of the files on your disc and compared them to the size (NOT size on disk) of your original files to verify they are the exact same size?

Comment: Yes, files on DVD have exact same size and content as originals.

Comment: If there are a bunch of small files, sector size might be the reason. DVDs use 2048 byte sectors and most OSs use something smaller (512 bytes for NTFS, for example), so a file that runs into a sector (but is less than 512 bytes) would take 2k on the CD and only 0.5k on your hard drive.

Comment: There are two files with less size than 2048 bytes and two files with much larger size. Total only 4 files.

Comment: I am not sure so I am not posting this as an answer: Could the Lead-In and the Lead-Out eat 4 MB? I mean for each writing it creates a new session on the disc.

Comment: @sinni800 - add this as an answer and I'll delete mine.

Comment: Nah, don't sweat it. I don't want to sound jealous or anything :).

Comment: Hahahahaha. Fine with me. It's 30 rep points, but I did offer :-)

Answer (score 3):

As @sinni800 pointed out above in the comments, this is your Lead-In and Lead-Out data (and table of contents, possibly) using up that additional space.

Comment: You could've just told me I had the right answer. I'd have posted it ;)

Answer (score -3):

[Internal fragmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_%28computer%29) says:

> Internal fragmentation occurs when storage is allocated without intention to use it. This space is wasted. While this seems foolish, it is often accepted in return for increased efficiency or simplicity.

Comment: How would that happen in something freshly written?

Comment: Please explain better.  Providing a link isn't sufficient, summarize what's there.

Comment: After inserting disk Windows 7 displayed standard dialog for new disk (question about disk label and format). All was freshly written only once in one session to a brand new disk. I have no third party buring software or non-system burning drivers.

Comment: I've voted this answer down because it does not address the problem, and is not summarised sufficiently.